# How to read from a file in asp?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a .asp file in
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb\

and I have a path to a file
C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\h.ics

How can I write the asp code that it will read the contents of h.ics and write it on the page?

Comment: Would you like it to act like everything written in "h.ics" is inside the code (like a copy/paste) or do you want to just simply display the file's contents?

Comment: @JeremyThompson What do you mean "using the FSO"?

Comment: @Alex.Piechowski as per my answer, FSO stands for File System Object. Gosh putting a link to my own answer in my answer - StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Use the File system Object, here is an example from Chris Muander (Codeproject founder)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251/Reading-a-text-file-in-ASP

Comment: Jeremy, that's not an exact duplicate, you linked to this very same question!

Comment: @bfavaretto, better yet, to the same answer!

Comment: I get this error:   
Server.MapPath() error 'ASP 0172 : 80004005'

Invalid Path

/MyWeb/test1.asp, line 42

The Path parameter for the MapPath method must be a virtual path. A physical path was used.

Comment: lmfao - hahaha - the google index is too quick

Comment: The google index on things like this are near instant, because it is very popular and is often changing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean ASP not ASP.NET. To read a file with ASP, you first need to create a FileSystemObject

So your code could something like the following (assuming you have the necessary permissions, etc):
(I have simplified it from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251/Reading-a-text-file-in-ASP)

```
<% Option Explicit

Const Filename = "C:/Users/Ryan/Desktop/h.ics"    ' file to read
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

Dim FSO
set FSO = server.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if FSO.FileExists(Filename) Then

    Set ts= FSO.OpenTextFile(Filename, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)

    ' Read file in one hit
    Dim Contents
    Contents = TextStream.ReadAll
    Response.write "File contents: " & Contents
    TextStream.Close
    Set TextStream = nothing

End If

Set FSO = nothing
%>
```

If you want to know more have a look at the following articles:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251/Reading-a-text-file-in-ASP
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7296/Reading-Files-in-ASP-and-How-to-Search-for-a-parti

Comment: yes, this is for asp classic, also the code isnt working, i think FSO.FileExists(Filename) is becoming false...

Comment: oops sorry, maybe try to change the Filename to have backward slashes instead of forward eg: Const Filename = "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\h.ics"

Comment: I don't believe the direction matters. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to go about this:

1. If you want the contents read from the file, you could use the "OpenTextFile Object":

   ```
   <%
   set t=fs.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\h.ics",1,false)
   x=t.ReadAll
   t.close
   Response.Write("The text in the file is: " & x)
   %>
   ```
2. If you want to include the file similar to copy/paste within your asp, use "Include File":

Type this outside of your scripting tags:

```
    <!--#include file="C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\h.ics"-->
```